# Adding php variables together

Tags: php, variables

I am new here and a new developer, hope this hasn't been asked before and I will explain as best I can.

I'm developing a website for a clan that I play a game with (so for fun and practice) and the game has items which you can buy or sell. 
These 'items' have their prices live on the website, and I would like to take the prices of 2 items and add them together to leave you with a price.

So, I am using wordpress with a plugin, tweaked the code and its dumps the variables in $data and $data2. I can echo these out and I get the numbers live on my website, so that part of the code is working.

I've tried things like :-

```html
$result = $data + $data2;

echo $result;
```

Within wordpress it removes the + 
Coding it with a template gives 0

Here is the address i am working on http://starhelpers.x10host.com/ge-test-page/

If you need more information do ask :)

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Hopefully this makes it clearer.

I am using a wordpress function which web scrapes content. The function is called wpws_get_content, you give it the URL and the CSS class you want to take and you can echo the result on the page.

```html
<?php

//so this grabs the first number
$data = wpws_get_content("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Vial_of_water/viewitem.ws?obj=227", "div.stats h3 span");

//this gets the secound number
$data2 = wpws_get_content("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Clean_avantoe/viewitem.ws?obj=261", "div.stats h3 span");

$result = $data + $data2;

echo $result;

//to test the variables are working (which are the numbers I would like to add)
echo $data;
echo $data2;

?>
```

So this code right now gives :-

```html
$result as 0
$data as 43 (on the page)
$data2 as 4,489 (on the page)
```

I'd like result to say 43 + 4489 = 4922
so $result would echo 4922.

Hopefully this makes it more clearer.

Comment: @bcesars do you enjoy laughing at others that know less than you? should your peers laugh at you when you dont understand something they consider to be easy?

Comment: Are you receiving the data as an int? You could try casting to an int using something like: if(is_numberic($data1) && is_numberic($data2)){ $result = (int)$data + (int)$data2; }

Comment: i think i know what you mean and yes, $data and $data2 are populated with numbers.

Comment: i attempted the above code with no success

Answer (score 2):

yes you are right.

```html
<?php

    //Define and set your vars
    $data = 10;
    $data2 = 20;

    //Sum
    $result = $data + $data2;

    //Concat
    $result = $data . $data2;

    //Show result
    echo 'The result is: ' . $result;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I've made amendments to my post to explain a little further. The 'vars' are already defined, its adding those together I want to see if its possable

Comment: http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic take a minute and try to understand as much of this as you can. that should help.

Comment: @StevenDenslow You trying to concat two strings? $result = $data . $data2; use dot ( . )

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look, I'm not sure if this is possible, but you just got to ask to find out.

I'll take a look at my post and try and refine it futher